# Python VK API wall.createComment attachements

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть бот (Python 3.6), он комментирует новые записи в группе. С текстом все получилось без проблем, а приложить фото/видео не получается. Делаю все по документации to_attach = photo+userId_photoId, т.е. photoXXXXX_YYYYY. Какие варианты решения? Строка с отправкой:

```
vk.method('wall.createComment', {'post_id':post_id, 'owner_id':group_id, 'message': to_write,'attachements': to_attach })
```

Comment: Скорее всего прикрепляемые медиафайлы находятся не в открытом доступе. 
Попробуйте передать video-86529522_456239136, прикрепляется?

Comment: Не прикрепляет (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле называется attachments, а не attachements

Comment: Я еще никогда так глупо не ошибался

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так:

```
import vk
session = vk.Session(access_token='token')
api = vk.API(session)
my_id = -100000000
comment_text = "some text"
photo_id = "photo100000000_100000000" #можно несколько фотографий через запятую и без пробелов, добавление видео не сильно отличается
post_id = 1000
api.wall.createComment(owner_id = my_id, post_id = post_id, message = comment_text, attachments = photo_id)
```

**P.S.**  Я использовал библиотеку `vk`, а не `vk_api`.

Comment: Я использую либу vk_api import vk_api

Comment: @podgorny.nikon, потому и написал: _Я делал так_, что библиотеку другую использовал. vk_api не пользовался, так что ничем не могу помочь, извините.